# PHP | str_replace valid input with whitespace

Tags: php, input, str-replace

I have a form, where a user has to enter an email address.

I check if the email address already exists in the database, if it is, it sends an error alert, otherwise it records it.

I noticed that if the db contains the email: a@a.com and I insert a@a.com with white spaces, the code interprets it as a new email address and then passes it as non-existent and registration starts, a behavior that I do not want to.

To work around this I insert the code and my tests:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  
  $controlla_pro = mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT invite_email FROM  invite WHERE invite_email='$email'");
  $risultato_controllapro=mysqli_num_rows($controlla_pro);


   if($risultato_controllapro==0)
   {
     /*CODE OK*/
   }else{
          /*CODE NOT OK*/
        }
}
```

try not to validate email addresses with whitespace:

```
$email = $connessione->real_escape_string(str_replace(' ','',$_POST['email']));
```

But it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

another try but not work:

first: clean input

after: real_escape_string

```
$no_space_email = str_replace(' ','',$_POST['email']);
$email = $connessione->real_escape_string($no_space_email);
```

Comment: if you want to delete white spaces both start and end then use php ```trim()``` function. I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //do operation }else{echo "invalid email";}
```

This will validate all the invalid email and remove spaces or won't allow emails with spaces.

Comment: how to integrate this with: if($risultato_controllapro==0)

Comment: Paste the `if($risult...==0){}` inside the `//do operation` block

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  
  $controlla_pro = mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT invite_email FROM  invite WHERE invite_email='$email'");
  $risultato_controllapro=mysqli_num_rows($controlla_pro);
if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
         if($risultato_controllapro==0)
         {
         /*CODE OK*/
        }else{
          /*CODE NOT OK*/
        }
}else{
 echo "This email is invalid! Try another...";
}
   
}  //please format it @user14846903